# Yule-Walker equations (ARMA(1,1))

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima, white-noise

My professor assigned me this task:

Let $\{X_T\}$ be causal $ARMA(1,1)$ process, i.e. $X_t - \varphi X_{t-1} = Z_t + \theta Z_{t-1}, \ \ Z_t \sim WN(0,\sigma^2)$.

i) Using Yule-Walker equations, derive the covariance $r(k)$. 
ii) When $\{X_t\}$ is white noise process?

I have a few questions about this task. First of all, can somebody explain to me how I need to eliminate the $MA$ part from this process since Yule-Walker equations are used for $AR$ models? Secondly, the answer for part ii) is when $\varphi$ and $\theta$ are equal to zero? Or do there exist other options for $ARMA(1,1)$ to be a white noise process?